# How to Execute multiple command using nohup

Tags: shell, command-line, nohup

I need to execute multiple commands using `nohup`. Each command should be executed after the previous command.

I used this command as an example:

```
nohup wget $url && wget $url2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

However that command did not work.

What command should I use for this purpose?

Comment: do you the the `&` at the end of a `nohup`?

Comment: A more complicated example:
`nohup sh -c 'echo $SU_PASSWORD | /afs/cs/software/bin/reauth; python -u ~/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_sl_with_ddp.py --manual_loads_name sl_hdb1_5cnn_adam_cl_filter_size --filter_size 4 > $OUT_FILE 2> $ERR_FILE' > nohup.out$SLURM_JOBID &`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Wrap it in `sh -c`:

```
nohup sh -c 'wget "$0" && wget "$1"' "$url1" "$url2" > /dev/null &
```

Comment: when I launch nohup I get "nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout" so isn't the "2>&1" redundant?

Comment: Probably. I think when I wrote the answer I just copied it from the question.

Comment: do you the the `&` at the end of a `nohup`?

Answer (score 13):

Wouldn't it be far simpler to create your list of commands in a separate shell file, e.g. command.sh, without any nohup.

Then you call:

```
nohup bash command.sh
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. When I press enter after running nohup, it exits and does not keep running the script in the background

Comment: It doesn't work on the background.

Comment: do you the the `&` at the end of a `nohup`?

Answer (score 6):

Others have already answered about `nohup`. As a practical side note: I recommend doing this kind of thing within a `screen` or `tmux` session. That way you can disconnect, then reconnect later and see the output and final result.

Comment: This answer is great for interactive scenarios, but doesn't make sense for scripts or automation.

Answer (score 4):

It would be simpler like this:

```
nohup sh -c "wget $url && wget $url2" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This however may cause issues if the URLs contain special characters so for a safer option you can use:

```
nohup sh -c "wget \"$url\" && wget \"$url2\"" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: The only safe way to pass parameters to `sh -c` is via separate arguments, which can be accessed via the positional parameters (`$0`, `$1`, ...). There is no easy or simple way to quote arguments properly for string parsing. Your attempt to use escaped double quotes fails if `$url` itself contains double quotes. Try `a='problem"'; sh -c "echo \"$a\""` yourself and see - you should get a syntax error because `sh -c` tries to run `echo "problem""`.

Comment: @jw013 Out of interest, does your objection apply equally to the accepted answer by -oh. By you. Presumably not, then. But I don't understand why not! :-)

Comment: @JonathanHartley I'm not sure I understand your question. If you compare this answer to mine carefully you should notice a difference in the way `$url` and `$url2` are used.

Comment: @jw013 Ah, of course. I was being silly. Thank you for setting me straight.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to create an additional file with the sequential part of the script and call it with nohup. Although, if you're passing parameters, that's going to add a little bit extra work.

Answer (score 0):

A more complicated example:

```
nohup sh -c 'echo $SU_PASSWORD | /afs/cs/software/bin/reauth; python -u ~/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_sl_with_ddp.py --manual_loads_name sl_hdb1_5cnn_adam_cl_filter_size --filter_size 4 > $OUT_FILE 2> $ERR_FILE' > nohup.out$SLURM_JOBID &
```

Answer (score -2):

might be helpful for someone:

```
nohup $(wget $url && wget $url2) &
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you explain the purpose of the command substitution? In its current form, your solution would try to execute the output generated by the two `wget` calls in a `nohup` environment.

Comment: Thanks @AdminBee :) Correct, both wget will output to hohup and for nohup it is like one single command