# execute multiple commands after ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, nohup

I need to pass a bash command into another process that needs to do the following:

1. ssh into a computer.  This does not require a password prompt.
2. set up some environment variables:  source path/to/script.sh
3. launch a gui program that requires (2).

Thus far, I have the following:

```
ssh -n -f pc-name -XYC nohup source folder/setup_thing.sh; program
```

For my efforts I get:

```
nohup: failed to run command `source': No such file or directory
bash: program: command not found
```

I've tried fixes like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47230/how-to-execute-multiple-command-using-nohup) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349262/run-a-nohup-command-over-ssh-then-disconnect) and several other similar answers.  I can't just put all of these in a bash file and then just call `ssh mySever 'nohup bash myscript.sh'`.

How to I restructure the above command such that it executes successfully?

Comment: @Anthon.  Better?

Comment: It's still not clear why you can't just put it all in a script, that would be the obvious way to restructure your solution,without quotes the `;` terminates the `ssh` command, so you are trying to run the GUI locally. Is that what you want ?

Comment: @Roman Yes. Adding a real question to your post, allows you to refocus the the attention of the reader to what actually needs to be resolved (especially important after providing contextual information that might or might not be relevant). With less guesswork there is just a higher chance on a working answer.

Comment: @XTian.  Because I'm working within a much larger framework where doing IO adds unnecessary amount of complexity.  And because its possible to do in one line like Archemar has so elegantly shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try

```
 ssh -n -f pc-name -XYC ". folder/setup_thing.sh; nohup  program &"
```

- `. folder/setup_thing.sh` will init variable from setup_thing.sh.
- `nohup  program &` will run program in backgroup, and return from ssh (due to nohup)"

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  Though I don't need to run it as a background process with `&`.

Comment: then skip both nohup and &.

Comment: I know this is a question all of its own, but I can't find an easy reference to what these arguments mean (http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html doesn't explain any of these).  What are they?

Comment: @Roman: Because they aren't ssh related. They're shell related--just like your entire question, really.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
nohup ssh -n -f pc-name -XYC "source folder/setup_thing.sh; program"
```

and it worked.  Though it does tell me that

```
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
```

Comment: Well, then, leave off the `nohup`!