# Can't run multiple files with nohup

Tags: command-line, nohup

This is what which is happening

```
[4]+  Stopped                 sudo nohup exec php socket_axd.php
adnan@vm085:~/server/axdchat/Server$ sudo nohup exec php socket_axd.php &
[5] 2312
adnan@vm085:~/server/axdchat/Server$ sudo nohup exec php axd.com.php  &
[6] 2321

[5]+  Stopped                 sudo nohup exec php socket_axd.php
adnan@vm085:~/server/axdchat/Server$
```

I want to run multiple files in background.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47230/how-to-execute-multiple-command-using-nohup

Comment: @coffeMug something like that but I do i change it to run for PHP based files?

Answer (score 1):

When a background job re-appears with a messge like `[5]+  Stopped`, it means it was stopped because it is trying to read from the terminal.

Usually gnu `nohup` redirects stdin to `/dev/null`, but perhaps your version does not. Try adding `</dev/null` to your commands, or look at the `setsid` command (to change session) if you have it.